# Error message as - The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference in visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

```
          **<p>(! c.FirstName &''& c.lastName)</p>**
  (Error:The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference in visualforce)
         </apex:repeat>
      </apex:outputPanel>
```

This is the error I'm getting. Can anyone please tell me what changes to make in the VF page to display the contact's First and Last names.

Answer (score 0):

for ampersand you have to use 
&amp;

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code

```
         <apex:outputPanel id="contactdisplay">
           <apex:repeat value="{! contactinformation }" var="c">
           *<p>{! c.Firstname &' '& c.LastName}</p>*
           </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Note - Make use of flowerbrackets.